# C - Characters not displayed correctly in output

Tags: c, character

I can insert the `è` character in my source code, but this is not correctly displayed in output in my program; in its place the `Þ` character appears.

The `è` character in the ASCII Extended corresponds to the`138`.

The `è` character in Unicode matches the`232` number.

The `Þ` character in ASCII Extended corresponds to the`232` number.

The `Þ` character in Unicode matches the`222` number.

Through debugger it is possible to notice that the compiler converts `è` with the number`232` and translates the integer `138` as the character `Š` (Line Tabulation Set), while in output the character number `232` is represented as `Þ` and the character number `138` is represented as `è`.

What's happening behind the scenes?

**Sample code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    unsigned char a = 'è';
    unsigned char b = 138;

    printf ("Char a:% c \ n", a);
    printf ("Char a:% d \ n \ n", a);
    printf ("Char b:% c \ n", b);
    printf ("Char b:% d \ n \ n", b);

    return 0;
 }
```

**Output:**

```
Char a: Þ
Char to: 232
    
Char b: 'è'
Char b: 138
```

**What the debugger sees:**

```
char a = 232 'è'
char b = 138 'Š'
```

Comment: What is the character code of your source code? Do you get compiler warnings like "implementation-defined multi-char character literal"?

Comment: I do not receive any warning message, I do not know what exactly is my 'source character code'.

Comment: But in the settings of my IDE Code :: Blocks in the "Editor> Encoding settings" section I find the "WINDOWS-1252" entry enabled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you're on Windows.

What happens is that your source code is in Unicode and so the `è` character is encoded as number 232. The compiler use this value in the generated program.

When your program is executed, this code is sent as parameter to the `printf` function, but as Windows use Extended ASCII, it is interpreted as `Þ` when printing it in the console.

You can encode your files in Extended ASCII to have the correct characters.

To determine which encoding your console uses, you can use this in Windows :

```
#include <windows.h>
unsigned cp = GetConsoleOutputCP();
```

You can change console encoding with this :

```
#include <windows.h>
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252); //Set console encoding to Windows 1252
SetConsoleOutputCP(65001); //Set console encoding to utf8
```

This sets the console output but not the console input, so if you need to deal with extended ASCII user input you need to use [GetConsoleCP()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolecp) and [SetConsoleCP()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecp) to set the input encoding.

You can see other available code page codes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/Intl/code-page-identifiers).

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows. In the settings of my IDE Code :: Blocks in the "Editor> Encoding settings" section I find the "WINDOWS-1252" entry enabled.

Comment: Can you print the result of `unsigned cp = GetConsoleOutputCP();` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleoutputcp

Comment: I get a message error: `'GetConsoleOutputCP' was not declared in this scope'`

Comment: Yes you should include windows.h I forgot to mention it sorry: `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: I get a result of `850`

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/Intl/code-page-identifiers) your console is in ibm850 code page. You can use `SetConsoleOutputCP(1252)` to set the console code page to Windows-1252 (like your files) or `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)` to set console code page to utf8, as it is more standard (and then change your file encoding to utf8). You could also change your file encoding to ibm850 but I doubt Code::Blocks can do so

Answer (score 0):

Just check that if you will write:

```
  printf("%d\n\n", 'è');
```

Then you will see that the char is not enough to contain correct value.

Comment: If I execute that statement I get `-24`, but I do not think this happens because char can not hold `è` value, but because the integer is interpreted in `printf` as signed by `%d`. If my `char` variable is declared as `unsigned` it can hold and then display all the characters of the extended ASCII table up to `255`.